# TinyMCE completely destroying html

Tags: tinymce

Trying to paste in some html into the  option on the TinyMCE editor that reads as follows:

```
<textarea onclick="this.focus(); this.select(); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Infographic', 'Click', 'marketing-infographic']);" rows="2">
  <img src="my_image.jpg" width="120" height="136" / >
  View full image
  <a href="https://site.com/my_image.jpg" />
</textarea>
```

...when updated, Tiny completely rewrites it to, well, something completely different.

```
<p>
  <img src="my_image.jpg" height="136" width="120" />
  <textarea style="height: 44px; width: 300px; margin: 2px;" onclick="this.focus(); this.select(); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Infographic', 'Click', 'marketing-infographic']);" rows="2">
    View full image
  </textarea>
  <a href="https://site.com/my_image.jpg" title="”Infographic”"> </a>
</p>
```

I've looked around the forum and here for help, the likes of...

```
cleanup_on_startup: false,
trim_span_elements: false,
verify_html: false,
cleanup: false,
convert_urls: false
```

...don't seem to be helping at all.  Is there away to allow for this kind of html to be entered via the editor without it getting completely bastardised?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the tinymce configuration parameters [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) and [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children) and set all relevant html elements and attributes as valid.